# How do I get started in C using avr-gcc on the mega2560

Tags: c, atmega, avrdude

I've program the arduino using tools before (on windows) and using C++ but never with c++ without tools nor done it on linux

I have a (at)mega2560 and want to do a simple blink program like the below

```
int LED_BUILTIN=13
void setup() {
    pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
    delay(1000); 
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
    delay(1000);
}
```

I'm completely clueless how to implement this. The only thing I figured out is `_delay_ms` and the command line args I should be using (which may be wrong)

> avr-gcc src.c -DF_CPU=16000000 -mmcu=atmega2560 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Os
> avr-objcopy -j .text -j .data -O ihex a.out my.hex
> avrdude -patmega2560 -cwiring -P/dev/ttyACM0 -b115200 -D -Uflash:w:my.hex:i

```
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <avr/io.h>

int led = 13;

inline void digitalWrite(int led, bool isHigh)
{
    //No idea
}

int main()
{
    //pinMode(led, 1);
    DDRB &= ~(1<<led); //I doubt this is right
    for(;;)
    {
        digitalWrite(led, 1);
        _delay_ms(1000);
        digitalWrite(led, 0);
        _delay_ms(1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: This question is too broad for this site. You should start with Atmel's code samples, learn how to configure your hardware and go from there.

Comment: Which pin on the mega2560 do you want to use for the LED? Go find the datasheet and give the actual pin name (for example PB3). There is no "pin 13" on an actual AVR, that's all abstractions by the Arduino libraries. Shifting a 1 thirteen bits to the left and then trying to assign it to a 8 bit register should be a clue.

Comment: @LiorBilia I have no idea what to google even if I wanted to do your suggestion. None of these look like your suggestion and everything leads me to this page https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/ATmega2560

Comment: @Unimportant do you have any idea how difficult it is just to find your suggestion? It turns out I had to look up mega2560 **rev 3** AND it was NOT on the atmel site (at least the one I end up looking at wasnt there). The PIN I suspect is PB7. It's a built in LED not one I wired up. It's 'D13` (13th digital pin) according to other pages

Comment: @EricStotch If it's `PB7` then change to `int led = 7`, `DDRB |= (1U << led);` and in `digitalWrite` function `if (isHigh) { PORTB |= (1U << led); } else { PORTB &= ~(1U << led); }`

Comment: @Unimportant thank you! I found a sample online that says `DDRC |= _BV(DDC3); //set as input`. _BV appears to be `1U<<n` so its doing what you suggested (and I confirmed it works). The [arduino ide sample](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BuiltInExamples/Blink) they call it `pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);`. I'm pretty confused. Is the comment wrong and he meants output or do I need to relearn some terminology?

Comment: @EricStotch Setting a bit in a DDR register makes the corresponding pin a output on AVR. So the comment is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try leveraging the existing [Arduino library](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/tree/master/cores/arduino). Arduino.h and wiring_digital.c are of particular note here and implement the functions you were originally using.

Comment: TY. It turns out it's on my system at `/usr/share/arduino/hardware/archlinux-arduino/avr/cores/arduino/wiring_digital.c`. How do people typically use this? I don't think I see a precompiled binary but I seemed to have figured out how I could compile it if I really wanted to. I just don't know if there's a simple idiomatic way

Comment: You will need to modify the gcc command to include that path. Take a look at this answer from a similar question... https://stackoverflow.com/a/16365360/970015

Answer (score 1):

There's probably hundreds of sites with examples like this. Here's one: https://toastedcornflakes.github.io/articles/avr_getting_started.html
(Yes, it's a '328 not a '2560, but for one led, it's close enough to get us started.)

Also check out the support files at Microchip.com for the ATmega328 and ATmega2560.  There's going to be examples and application notes there.

Also get familiar with what AVR libc gives us - see http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/ and
http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/modules.html